# Element is in first half of the list, Haskell

Tags: haskell

Reading the book Get Programming with Haskell, one of the questions was to find if a given element is in the first half of a list. This can be done as

```
isInFirstHalf x xs = elem x firstHalf
    where firstHalf = take (length xs `div` 2) xs
```

However, the problem is that here `length` traverses the whole list. In an imperative language, one can shortcircut the loop early by keeping track of the element index and the current counter. E.g. if the list has a million elements, and there was a match on the third element, once you finish looping through the sixth element, you can immediately return true.

My question is if there's a way to implement something like this in Haskell.

Comment: You can sure keep track of the index, but how do you know if the index ends up in the first half? You still need length for that. The difference with most imperative languages is that most of them use arrays, not lists (even if they call them lists), where length is O(1). And guess what? Haskell has arrays too!

Comment: @FyodorSoikin have you missed this part in the Q, "E.g. if the list has a million elements, and there was a match on the third element, once you finish looping through the sixth element, you can immediately return true"? :)

Comment: Ah, yes, I totally did

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure.

```
halfAsLong (x:_:xs) = x:halfAsLong xs
halfAsLong _ = []

isInFirstHalf x xs = elem x (zipWith const xs (halfAsLong xs))
```

Try it out:

```
> isInFirstHalf 3 (1:2:3:4:5:6:undefined)
True
```

Exercises for the reader:

- Where did the element index and current counter of your proposed imperative solution go? (They are still in there, just hidden in a way I think is a bit subtle!)
- This rounds down when dividing odd lengths in half, like `` length xs `div` 2 `` does. How would the code have to change to round up, like `` (length xs + 1) `div` 2 `` does?

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Wagner posted a very nice answer that shows that you don't really need indices, after all.

Still, if you do want to use indices, a solution can be crafted as follows.

- We enumerate all the list elements by pairing them with their indices. This is done by using `zip [0..] xs` (or `zip [1..] xs` if you want to start counting at 1).
- We find whether your `x` is in the list, and find its index `i` if it's present. One could proceed by direct recursion, or use something like `dropWhile ((/= x) . fst) ...` and then test the result.
- Once we know `i`, we need to check whether there are at least `i` elements after that. This can be solved by direct recursion, or by `drop`ping `i-1` elements and testing whether the result is a non empty list.

There are other alternatives, of course. We could for instance skip enumerating elements with `zip [0..]` and use recursion by keeping track of the current index: `foo n x (y:ys) = ... foo (n+1) x ys ...`.

Comment: this isn't right. :( the Q specifically asks for the short-circuiting behavior.

Comment: @WillNess I think this only inspects the list as needed, achieving the needed short-circuiting. Did I miss something I can't see?

Comment: I mean if `x` is not present in the first half, or at all. or maybe I'm missing something... yep, I was. :) interesting...

Comment: well the only thing against this approach remains, if the `==` comparison is a non-trivial, heavy calculation. so yeah, still, it does more work than needed, potentially.

Comment: @WillNess I now think you are right: if `x` is not found, Daniel's solution can find `[]` early, and avoid using `==` after the first half. My solution would use `==` on all the list.

Comment: but if `x` is not found in the first half, the turtle-and-hare will still traverse the whole list. just like your solution. it's only in the number of calls to `==` where there's a difference. ah, and that it'd only force the 2nd half's spine while yours would also force the elements.

Comment: @WillNess Exactly. My solution is not as lazy as it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another way to think of the task. An element `x` appears in the first half of a list `xs`, excluding the midpoint, if there are strictly fewer elements before the first occurrence of the element than after it.

We can write `break (== x) xs` using the standard function `break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` to split `xs` into two parts: those appearing before `x` (or all of `xs`, if `x` is not found), and the remainder (including `x`, if it is found).

```
> break (== 0) []
([], [])

> break (== 0) [0, 1]
([], [0, 1])

> break (== 0) [1, 0]
([1], [0])

> break (== 0) [1, 2, 0, 3, 4]
([1, 2], [0, 3, 4])

> break (== 0) [1, 2, 3, 4]
([1, 2, 3, 4], [])
```

We then want to compare the lengths of these two parts without calculating the actual lengths strictly as `Int`. To do so, we can compute the *shape* of each part by ignoring all its elements, using `shape = map (const ())`, a.k.a. `void :: (Functor f) => f a -> f ()` specialised to lists.

```
shape :: [a] -> [()]
shape = void
```

The `Ord` instance for lists sorts them lexicographically, and all values of type `()` are equal—okay, the *only* value of type `()`—so a comparison of shapes `[()]` is a comparison of the lengths of the lists, which is also lazy enough for our purposes. (For maximal laziness, `shape` could be defined as `genericLength` on a lazy natural number type like `data N = Z | S N` with an appropriate `Ord` instance.)

```
> [] < repeat ()
True

> shape [5 .. 10] >= shape [1 .. 3]
True

> shape [1 .. 3] > shape [1 ..]
False
```

We can also “decrement” the shape of a list using `drop 1`, which we’ll use to skip counting the element itself if it was found. (Alternatively, we could “increment” the shape with `(() :)`.)

Finally, putting these elements together leads to a fairly simple solution:

```
isInFirstHalf :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
isInFirstHalf x xs = shape before < shape (drop 1 after)
  where
    (before, after) = break (== x) xs
```

Notice that if the element was not found, `after` will be empty, so `drop 1` will have no effect, but the shape of `before` can’t possibly be smaller than the empty shape `[]`, so the comparison `(<)` will still correctly return `False`.